# How to find the positive maximum value of this total profit function?

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, maximum

So I have this function and I want to find the maximum value and the plot for x
[image]
I'm not really sure if I wrote the integral function correctly in mathematica, but here is the code I attempt :

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Z = 1000;
W = 100000;
G = 250;
H = 100;
T = 38;
L = 4000;
P = 5;
S = 2.5;
Y = 2;
A = 0.1;
J = 8000;
a=1;
t=0.5;
Clear[f];
f[x_] = f[x_] = 1/x (Integrate[J*Z (1 - R/Y)^(1 - a*t + t), {R, 0,x}] -((W + T*G) + ((L + T*P)*Integrate[Z (1 - R/Y)^(1 - a*t), {R, 0, x}] + (H + T*S + A*L)*Integrate[Integrate[Z (1 - R/Y)^(1 - a*t), {R, v, T}], {t, 0, x}])));
Plot[Re@f[x], {x, 0, 2}]
FindMaximum[{Re@f[x], x > 0}, x]
```

Comment: Please post the formula by Mathematica code.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. In order to replicate and resolve the difficulty you face in our own notebooks, we need you to provide copy-paste-able Mathematica code. Copy directly from your input cell, click the `Edit` button under your post and format as code using the `{  }` icon in the Edit window. Thanks.

Comment: Oke, I already include my mathematica code

Comment: The double integral in your code is not the same as shown in the equation.

Comment: Compare this form of your code `(f[x_] = 1/x (Inactive[Integrate][J*Z (1 - R/Y)^(1 - a*t + t), {R, 0, x}] - ((W + T*G) + ((L + T*P)*Inactive[Integrate][Z (1 - R/Y)^(1 - a*t), {R, 0, x}] + (H + T*S + A*L)*Inactive[Integrate][Inactive[Integrate][Z (1 - R/Y)^(1 - a*t), {R, v, T}], {t, 0, x}])))) // TraditionalForm` with the image of the equation. We have no way of knowing which is correct. One or the other or both needs to be corrected so that they are in agreement.